# File -> Make... menu option is disabled in VB6 IDE

Tags: ide, vb6

VB6 IDE can get into a state when the Make XXXX menu option under the File Menu is disabled.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Found my own solution that did not require re-installing VB6.
In VB6, Right click on the toolbar, goto Customize and reset toolbars. 
Aftewards, the Make XXXX menu under the File menu is re-enabled!

Comment: mine was related to mztools.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this when the file(s) were read-only. Make the files read/write and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 IDE, go to menu View->Toolbars->Customize->Reset.